# Не получается проверить наличие записи в бд

Tags: php, laravel

Делаю запрос:

```
User::where('uid',$userInfo['uid'])->isEmpty();
```

Получаю ошибку:

```
BadMethodCallException in Builder.php line 2123:
Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::isEmpty()
```

Можно ли вообще так делать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Такого метода нет в билдере, есть несколько вариантов:

1. Через метод exists (самый лучший как по мне):

   ```
   if (User::where('uid',$userInfo['uid'])->exists()) {
       //Запись существует
   }
   ```
2. Через метод count:

   ```
   if (User::where('uid',$userInfo['uid'])->count() > 0) {
       //Запись существует
   }
   ```
3. Простой выборкой first и проверкой на null:

   ```
   $user = User::where('uid',$userInfo['uid'])->first();
   if ($user != null) {
       // Запись существует
   }
   ```